# Magento The Amount of times a product has been ordered

Tags: magento

I want to show the products that have been purchased the most 
so far i am using

```
      $_productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
                          ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                          ->addOrderedQty()
                          ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', $visibility)
                          ->setOrder('ordered_qty', 'desc');
```

BUT I want to count the amount of time the product has been purchased, disregarding the qty purchased. EG
a customer buys 20 X PRODUCT A (Count this as 1)
a customer buys 1 X PRODUCT B (Count this as 1)

This is because some products are bought in huge quantities so bestsellers data doesn't really reflect our most popular products.

Is this data available?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the access of MySQL database then you can easily get the list by query

```
SELECT sku, count(*)as qty FROM sales_flat_order_item
GROUP BY sku
ORDER BY qty desc
```

or you can also use Magento Resource Model to get the same

```
$query = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_item_collection');
$query->getSelect()->reset(Zend_Db_Select::COLUMNS)
        ->columns(array('sku','COUNT(*)'))
        ->group(array('sku'));
```